# Is following declaration of class atributes as None correct?

Tags: python, class

When & why would someone write class as follows:

```py
1.
class Cat:
    name = None
    age = None

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

instead of simple:

```py
2.
class Cat:
   def __init__(self, name, age):
       self.name = name
       self.age = age
```

or with general class attribute:

```py
3.
class Cat:
    species = 'mammal'

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

Would you ever use the #1. example? 
Would you consider it correct?

Comment: Unless someplace in the code specifically refers to `Cat.name` and `Cat.age`, they are just unnecessary noise. Class attributes are not related to instance attributes in any way.

Comment: @chepner - variable references fall back to the class if they are not satisfied by object's namespace. Suppose `foo = "bar"` had also been defined at the class level, then `print(self.foo)` would use it. In this `__init__` you could do something like `self.name = name if name else self.name` which would be a different way of making a default assignment besides just putting the default in the init signature. You could decide on the default dynamically at class load (maybe reading an .ini file). Not sure this is a _good_ idea, but possible.

Comment: Yes, but only when the instance attribute *does not exist*. You can't relate a class attribute to a non-existent thing.

Comment: @chepner - not sure what you mean. `self.name` can be an instance or class attribute. So you can relate the class attribute to a non-existent instance attribute. That's the reason for the fallback logic in python - if the instance attribute does not exist, fallback to the related class attribute.

Comment: `self.name` is an *expression* that can resolve to either an instance attribute or a class attribute. That doesn't make the two attributes related. Have I seen people using class attributes as "default" values for non-existent instance attributes? Yes. Have I ever seen anyone *recommend* doing that? No.

Comment: @chepner: I don’t know that I’d positively *recommend* the practice, but I would certainly accept it as a stylistic variation (only, of course, in cases where the constructor doesn’t unconditionally assign to them, it wouldn’t confuse a tool in use like Doxygen, and mutability of the “default” wasn’t an issue).  It might, for instance, let you inherit a constructor rather than writing a noise call to `super().__init__`.

Comment: The initializer (not constructor) *should* be setting instance attributes. Access to class attributes via an instance should be limited to a convenience to avoid `type(self).name`.